# Swing draws an image of lower quality than on the web

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

For Java swing, I'm trying to add an image in a panel and create the image using JLabel.

```
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel() { 
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(imageInputStream);
        double scale = 50 / bi.getHeight();
        g2.scale(scale, scale);
        g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

On web

```
<img src="imageURL"  hieght="50"/>
```

Why Swing draws the image, its quality is not as good as web. Why?

Comment: every code line has equivalent by using imageLabel.setIcon(myIcon)

Comment: 1. For scaling, you may want to use another interpolation method, see [RenderingHints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html). 2. When scaling down, for good quality you should do it in steps, instead of in one pass (keep halving the size, until the final step).

Comment: Don't read the image in paintComponent, do it upfront (in the constructor for example), otherwise your image is re-read every time your component is painted. Also, use `g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);` and not `g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);`